# Html: Overflow issue with span contain an image tag

Tags: css, overflow, html

I have a problem with overflow. I have a div that set to be overflow: hidden, and all the elements within it was set to position absolute. The elements itself is a span tag that contains text and a image tag. I have an arrow to control the span tag forward or backward within the div. Everything is fine but when I move the span tag towards the end of the div tag where part of it outside the div. The image within the span tag was word-wrap to a new row rather staying the same line of the text.

Do anyone know why is like, it is work fine if the span tag fully within the div?

Comment: I wanted to provide the code but the code was written in javascript  and css. Is hard for me to put the code here.

Comment: use [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent text from breaking to a new line, use the following CSS definition:

```
elementstyle {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Then, to make the image float next to the text, use this:

```
elementstyle img {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: @Simon Pleasure, glad I could help!